# What particular solution should I guess for this relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Just trying to solve a non-homogeneous recurrence relation:

$$f(n) = 2f(n-1) + n2^n$$

$$f(0) = 3$$

---

Characteristic equation is:

$$f(n) - 2f(n-1) = 0$$

$$a-2 = 0$$

$$a = 2$$

Homogeneous solution is:

$$f_H(n) = b_0\cdot (2)^n$$

---

Right-hand side is:

$$n2^n$$

**What is the particular guess I should be taking based on this?**

Comment: I think that $f_H(n)=b_02^n$.

Comment: @ajotatxe: This stuff confuses me. If we chose $b_0$ to replace $n$ there, why aren't we replacing the exponential $n$ too?

Comment: What @ajotatxe is saying is that if $a=2$, the form of the homogeneous solution is $2^n$ and not $(-2)^n$ as you have written.

Comment: @Omega : I don't get it. I corrected the sign as it is $2^n$ and you edited back to $(-2)^n$. Why? Do you think it is $-2$ and need help to clarify this?

Comment: @user88595: Oh no, actually, I saw your comment and said "yeah I should invert the sign" so I went and inverted it without realising you already had inverted so it returned to its original form lol.

Answer (score 8):

(This is not a guess, but rather an approach to finding the solution.)

Firstly, we rearrange the given relation to get:

$$f(n) - 2f(n-1) = n2^n$$

Divide throughout by $2^n$. This gives us:

$$\frac{f(n)}{2^n} - \frac{f(n-1)}{2^{n-1}} = n$$

Do a summation to exploit the potential cancellations on the LHS:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n\left(\frac{f(i)}{2^i} - \frac{f(i-1)}{2^{i-1}}\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^n i$$
$$\frac{f(n)}{2^n} - \frac{f(0)}{2^0} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$\frac{f(n)}{2^n} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 3$$
$$f(n) = 2^{n-1}(n^2 + n + 6)$$

---

In general, if you have stuffs like $a_n - ka_{n-1} = b_n$ where $k$ is a constant, dividing throughout by $k^n$ might be a good way to start.

Comment: How did you rearrange $f(n) = 2f(n-1) + n2^n$ to $f(n)-f(n-1) = n2^n$? I ask because of $2f(n-1)$, how did it become just $f(n-1)$?

Comment: I did two steps in one for that one. I've split them up to make it less confusing, do have a look.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Yiyuan Lee is very good and clever.

More generally, you will need to solve the homogeneous as you did and notice that $a = 2$. Then look at the RHS and notice that it also is $2^n$ so you need to look for a solutions of the form :
$$cn2^n$$
However this **is** the RHS so add a $n^2$ term to try finding a solution of the form :
$$(c_1n^2 + c_2n)2^n$$
Substitute this into the equation and solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Typo: you have $c_1$ twice in your suggested guess.

Comment: @rajb245 : cheers

Comment: Your answer directly answers the original question, and more generally shows the pattern of what to do when the forcing term already solves the homogeneous equation. Very nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: work it out in three steps.

1. Try something like the RHS, say $an2^n$.
2. If necessary modify this by including "lower order" terms - in this case, change the guess to $(an+b)2^n$.
3. Compare the homogeneous solution, here $f_H(n)=A2^n$.  If your guess has any terms shared with $f(n)$, multiply the guess by $n$.  Repeat until there are no shared terms.  In this case $(an+b)2^n$ has the term $b2^n$ in common with $f_H(n)$, so modify the guess to $(an^2+bn)2^n$.  There is now nothing in common with $f_H(n)$, so this is the one to go with.

Comment: Adding a $b$ in step 2 will not work as this is the solution to the homogeneous equation. This is the same as finding a constant which you'll add later on to the arbitrary constant.

Comment: @user88595, exactly!  That is why step 3 is there.  But you have to put the $b$ in there as otherwise you will end up with $an^22^n$ which will *not* in general give a solution.  And it is *not* the same as adding $b$, it is adding $b2^n$ (which as I have already explained will not b in the final answer anyway).

Comment: @user88595 notice that your final suggestion in your answer is in fact exactly the same as mine.  Sorry to have to say this but I think you should read answers *much* more carefully before commenting.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's just a different method. My point is that I simply add new powers of $n$ until it's enough as I know beforehand that the constant won't work avoiding eventual calculations. When I read your answer I understand step 2 is step 1 with another constant.

Comment: @user88595 how do you apply your method if it's a second order recurrence with homogeneous solution $(An+B)2^n$ and the right hand side is $n2^n$?

Comment: In that case I would go straight for $an^22^n$ as the lower terms are covered by arbitrary constants so there's no need to find them. I'll notice that it this special case it doesn't work (I get $a=0$) and try $(an^3 + bn^2)2^n$ which gives an answer.

Comment: Not sure if I have understood you correctly, but if you have to actually figure out the coefficients before you realise that it doesn't work, then that sounds to me like a rather clumsy method.  My method works fine in this case - try it.

Comment: If, hypothetically, there was yet *another* shared term between my guess and the $f(n)$, I would have to multiply the guess by $n$ **again**, right? In that case the guess would be $(an^3+bn^2)2^n$?

Comment: @Omega, that's right.  This could happen with a second order recurrence having $(An+B)2^n$ in the homogeneous solution and $n2^n$ on the RHS.  I would go (1) $an2^n$; (2) $(an+b)2^n$ - doesn't work; (3) $(an^2+bn)2^n$ - still doesn't work; (3 again) $(an^3+bn^2)2^n$ and this will work.

Comment: I'm trying to apply this with another exercise at the moment. *"If necessary modify this by including "lower order" terms"* - what determines whether it is necessary or not to include lower order terms?

Comment: You always add lower order terms if there are any.  The "if necessary" was intended to exclude cases like $RHS=2^n$ in which there aren't any lower order terms.  Sorry, maybe I didn't write that very clearly.

Comment: I'm working on one where the homogeneous solution is $(b_0+b_0n)\cdot(-3)^n$ and $RHS = 4 + 3^n$. In this case, I don't need to add a lower order term right?

Comment: That's right.  And you don't need step 3 either, because a constant times $3^n$ is not the same as a constant times $(-3)^n$.

Comment: In step 1, *"try something like RHS"*, can you elaborate on that? In this example, where $RHS = n2^n$, you decided to use $an2^n$. I do see that your decision is "like the RHS", but what made you specifically choose this and not something else? Or is it just a matter of copy-pasting the RHS? Basically, if I had $RHS = 4+3^n$, would it be $a4+a3^n$?

Comment: Use the RHS, but modified so that each term is multiplied by an unknown constant.   So if $RHS=2+3\times4^n$ you would start with $a+b\times4^n$.

Comment: If I multiply each term by an unknown constant, wouldn't it be $2a+3b\times4^n$ instead?

Comment: Ok, doing what you said, for an $RHS = 4+3^n$ it would be $a+b\cdot 3^n$?

Comment: Both of your last two suggestions are fine, because you have yet to evaluate the constants.  It doesn't matter if your solution comes out as, for example, $14+15\times4^n$ or $2\times7+3\times5\times4^n$,

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to compute some values and I found this formula:

$$f(n)=3\cdot2^n+\frac{n^2+n}22^n$$

It is easy to prove it by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Just solve the bugger by using generating functions. Define $F(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} f(n) z^n$, adjust indices so there aren't subtractions:
$$
f(n + 1) = 2 f(n) + (n + 1) 2^{n + 1}
$$
Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} f(n + 1) z^n    &= \frac{F(z) - f(0)}{z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} (2 z)^n         &= \frac{1}{1 - 2 z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} n 2^n z^{n - 1} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1}{1 - 2 z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} (n + 1) 2^{n + 1} z^n
                               &= \frac{2}{(1 - 2 z)^2}
\end{align}
This gives:
$$
\frac{F(z) - 3}{z} = 2 F(z) + \frac{2}{(1 - 2 z)^2}
$$
Solving for $F(z)$, as partial fractions:
$$
F(z) = \frac{3}{1 - 2 z} - \frac{1}{(1 - 2 z)^2} + \frac{1}{(1 - 2 z)^3}
$$
Using the generalized binomial theorem:
\begin{align}
f(n) &= 3 \binom{-1}{n} (-2)^n - \binom{-2}{n} (-2)^n + \binom{-3}{n} (-2)^n \\
     &= 3 \cdot 2^n - (n + 1) 2^n + \frac{(n + 2) (n + 1)}{2} 2^n \\
     &= (n^2 + n + 6) \cdot 2^{n - 1}
\end{align}
At first glance, this checks, as $f(0) = 3$.